# Why does this operator not get inherited?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have the following code:

```cc
#include <iostream>

class Base {
  public:
    virtual void operator()(int &x) = 0;
    void operator()(int &&x) {
        operator()(x);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    void operator()(int &x) {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived derived;
    derived(10);
}
```

I expect that a call to `operator()` on a `Derived` will try to call a `Base::operator()` overload (because the inheritance is `public`), which will call `void Base::operator()(int &&x)` (because the expression is an rvalue), which will call `void Base::operator()(int &x)` with a reference to the `x` variable that was bound to `10`. Why does this not happen?

In particular the error message is:

```
Documents/fubar.cc:20:5: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'Derived'
    derived(10);
    ^~~~~~~
Documents/fubar.cc:13:10: note: candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
    void operator()(int &x) {
         ^
```

Comment: OK, can you post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Ah, I have found this is a duplicate

Comment: Don’t get distracted by the operator. You’ll have the same problem with any function name.

Answer (score 3):

The `Derived::operator()(int&)` declaration hides the `Base::operator()(int&&)`.

You can reintroduce the hidden declaration by adding `using Base::operator()` in the Derived class.